# Setting up an additional wireless access point

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, wifi-configuration

I have a Zyxel NWA1123-AC (not V2) that I wish to use as an additional access point on my network. I have a wireless router that sits in one end on the house, and the NWA1123-AC will be connected to it by a cable in the other end of the house. Both devices support both 2,4 GHz and 5 GHz wifi. Ideally, the NWA1123-AC would have the same SSID and authentication as the primary wireless router so that the wifi is seamless throughout the house.
Can someone please explain what setup is needed to achieve this, or point me to a guide? I feel I have tried many different configurations across different AP modes, but none gave me the experience that I desire. I admit, while I am quite technically adept, I am no network expert, and the amount of options in the NWA1123-AC is a little overwhelming.

Thank you!

Comment: Having two routers with the same SSID has not be seamless in my experience.  I use a Ubiquiti AP Lite here (on an Ethernet cable) to extend wireless to the upstairs floor. The wireless is seamless for phones and laptop when changing floors.  Food for thought.

Comment: To be clear, I only have one router. The Zyxel is fairly advanced, but it is still just an access point. Do you use different SSID for your setup? In any case, I have been to a ton of places (offices, schools, malls) where they have multiple AP setup with same SSID, so it clearly _can_ be done.

Comment: I just use one SSID for my complete wireless network.